# What() method for std::exception isn't acting virtual?

Tags: c++, exception, c++11, virtual

So in the reference manual, the what() method is described as virtual, but it doesn't seem to be acting that way. (I am compiling with g++ and the c++11 flag)

```
#include <stdio.h> //printf
#include <iostream> //cout
#include <stdexcept>// std::invalid_argument
using namespace std;

void fn(){
    throw runtime_error("wowwowo");
}

int main(){
    try {fn(); }
    catch(exception a) {cout << a.what() << endl;}
    return 0;
}
```

The output for this is "std::exception", as opposed to the error message, "wowwowo". However, if I change the catch type to runtime_error, it behaves as expected. I have some code where I would like to catch exceptions that may or may not be runtime_errors, and I suppose I could have multiple catch blocks, but I'm curious as to why the code behaves as it does. Here's the code that prints out the error message:

```
#include <stdio.h> //printf
#include <iostream> //cout
#include <stdexcept>// std::invalid_argument
using namespace std;

void fn(){
    throw runtime_error("wowwowo");
}

int main(){
    try {fn(); }
    catch(runtime_error a) {cout << a.what() << endl;}
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change this statement:

```
catch(exception a) {cout << a.what() << endl;}
```

to this:

```
catch(const exception &a) {cout << a.what() << endl;}
```

You have to catch an exception **by reference** in order for it to use polymorphism. Otherwise, you are slicing the `std::runtime_error` object so only a `std::exception` object remains, thus `std::exception::what()` will be called instead of `std::runtime_error::what()`.

As for the function itself, it is indeed a `virtual` function.

```
class exception {
public:
    //...
    virtual const char* what() const noexcept;
};
```

Comment: Failing to catch by reference results in [slicing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing).

Comment: @Mark Ransom All this time I have being tried to recall the English word slicing.:). Thanks.

Comment: Ahhh, thank you both. Gotta run, I'll accept thios answer later.